# Open FGA Wildcard Relationship From Object to User

Tags: authorization, identity, access-control, identity-management, role-based-access-control

I am trying to define user and admin schema in OpenFga

```
model
  schema 1.1
type user
  relations
    define admin: [admin#member]
type admin
  relations
    define member: [user]
```

I have added relationship where I have a user to admin relationship

```
User     admin:identity_admin
Relation admin
Object   user:rahul
```

I want to add a relationship wher all future user's admin should be `admin:identity_admin`. Something like

```
User     admin:identity_admin
Relation admin
Object   user:*
```

But seems like this is not supported by OpenFGA or I may be missing something. Any help will be appriciated

Open FGA Playground Link: https://play.fga.dev/sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
model
  schema 1.1
type user
  
type admin
  relations
    define admin_by: [user, user:*]
```

Then write this tuple:

```
USER: user:*
RELATION: admin_by
OBJECT: admin:identity_admin
```

Then calls of the form `is user:X related to admin:identity_admin as admin_by?` will be `true` for any `X`.